# How to block (ban, forbid) specific dependency in MSBuild SDK style project (C#)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, dependency-management, msbuild-task

I have an application, consist of a few projects (e.g., `projects A, B`), each of them has several direct dependencies, added via `<PackageReference Include=...`. These dependencies has another dependencies, which I get "for free" (aka transitive dependencies).

```
project A -> library 1
project A -> library 2
project A -> library 3
project B -> library 2
project A -> library 1

library 1 -> Transitive library X
library 3 -> Transitive library Y
```

I would like to ban / forbid / block specific dependency in my code base. Meaning, I want to fail all builds, which try to use it directly. For example, in my case I want to block `Transitive library Y`. So If someone creates a new change, which uses it in their code, I need to fail such build.

Is there any standard way to do it? Or I should manually get all dependencies, analyze them as a text, and so on (e.g., create such MsBuild task, or task in my CI/CD).

Comment: `PackageReference` is an Item collection. You can add a custom target that runs `BeforeBuild` to check the `PackageReference` collection and report an error if library Y has been referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this code works for me. I put it into [Directory.Packages.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management).

```
<GlobalPackageReference ExcludeAssets="build" Include="Transitive library Y">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</GlobalPackageReference>
```

Effectively, I just included that `Transitive library Y` as direct dependency, globally (via Central Package Management), but I forbid `compile` [action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). As result, I still can use it in runtime through other dependencies, but I cannot add my code, which will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using this linter - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md